# Javascript - UTC Time to Local Time Conversion

Tags: javascript

There is a lot of similar questions on StackOverflow on how to accomplish converting UTC time to Loca Time with libraries, but nothing really addresses how to do this with the tools the Javascript provides us.

Currently, I have a string like so: `13:05`.

To convert it to UTC, I would do something like:

```js
const d = new Date(), time = "13:05";
const localToUtc = new Date(`${d.getUTCMonth()}-${d.getUTCDate()}-${d.getUTCFullYear()} ${time}`)
   .toISOString()
   .substring(11, 16);

console.log(localToUtc);
```

But I have no clue how I would convert it to do the opposite approach and convert UTC time to local time. Does anyone have any suggestions? Please note, that I don't want to select a timezone I want to use whatever my computer is currently on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Date` constructor that takes individual date and time component values rather than a date string. This way the `dateString` that you pass in can have optional seconds if you wish.

Do not use this:

> new Date(dateString)

Use this instead:

> new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]])

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

---

## Example

```js
const localToUtc = timeStr => {
  const date = new Date()
  const tokens = timeStr.split(':').map(t => parseInt(t, 10))
  return new Date(
      date.getUTCFullYear(),
      date.getUTCMonth(),
      date.getUTCDate(),
      tokens[0],             // hours
      tokens[1],             // minutes
      tokens[2] || 0         // seconds (optional)
    )
   .toISOString()
   .substring(11, 16)
}

const utcToLocal = timeStr => {
  const date = new Date()
  const tokens = timeStr.split(':').map(t => parseInt(t, 10))
  const result = new Date(
      date.getUTCFullYear(),
      date.getUTCMonth(),
      date.getUTCDate(),
      tokens[0],             // hours
      tokens[1],             // minutes
      tokens[2] || 0         // seconds (optional)
    )
   result.setMinutes(result.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset())
   return result.toString().substring(16, 21)
}

console.log(`UTC time   : ${localToUtc('13:05')}`);
console.log(`Local time : ${utcToLocal('17:05')}`);
```

Comment: this looks wonderful. I'm just confused about where the hours get changed in utcToLocal. It looks like you set the minutes based off the timeZone offset but not the hours?

Comment: @bryan The timezone offset is in minutes.